# What does the pair of paired vertical lines mean in this piecewise equation?

Tags: notation

In the following equation

[image]

(which is equation 3-43 from https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA317762.pdf)

How should I interpret the two sets of paired lines? I'm used to seeing one, with the left hand side being the equation to use based on the right hand side condition being met. What's with the middle section here?

Comment: Maybe just brackets? Would that make sense in context?

Comment: Some kind of norm possibly.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified in the text, I'd assume it's a Euclidean norm.

Comment: It's not a vector equation though, all of those are scalar numbers. But now I'm realizing that maybe it's supposed to be a floor function.